# GAE Google AppEngine - How to handle subdomain in-app routing in Python27 threadsafe?

Tags: google-app-engine, thread-safety, python-2.7

I used to do this in GAE Python25 to handle in-app routing of requests to www.example.com and blog.example.com (Notice the difference in subdomains) within the same app, using the code below:

```
#app.yaml
- url: /
  script: main.py

#main.py
applications = {
  'www.example.com': webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                                      debug=False),
  'blog.example.com': webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', BlogHandler)],
                                      debug=False)
}

def main():
    host = os.environ['HTTP_HOST']
    if host in applications:
        run_wsgi_app(applications[host])
    else:
        run_wsgi_app(applications['www.example.com'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

But in Python27, the format is something different. It's the following:

```
#app.yaml
handlers:
- url: /
  script: main.app  # (instead of main.py)


#main.py
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([(r'/', MainPage)],debug=True)
```

How do I achieve the same functionality in Python27 (threadsafe), and route different subdomains to different handlers within the app?

Thanks!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use webapp2 domain routing http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#domain-and-subdomain-routing

Answer (score 0):

You need todo it on the handler level, something like this:

```
#main.py
applications = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', GlobalMainHandler)], debug=False)
```

and in the handler:

```
class GlobalMainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    if self.request.host.startswith('blog'): #not sure it is called host, but its there
      self.blog_main()
    else:
      self.the_other_main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It turns out webapp2 has domain and subdomain advanced routing capabilities built into it. You might want to check out the answer above. :)

Comment: @Albert Yes, I totally forgot about that. that's indeed the current answer.