# How to create a simple multiple domain site for gae?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Here is the situation: 
Got www.mysite.com and demo.mysite.com.

Both the site point to www.mysite.com.  Want to be able to have another site on demo.mysite.com. How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you already read this https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain ?

Comment: yah, i'm on More About Wildcard Subdomain Mapping. but don't understand what to do there.

Comment: There are some ways to do that: 1) create multiple apps or 2) handle subdomains in-app (http://stackoverflow.com/q/9818019/126125)